# How to use multiple transactioManager in each ItemReader and ItemWriter in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-java-config

I'm using spring batch with java config.(batch-core 3)

I use 2 datasource.

for read DB (A). for write DB (B).

I want to write Job configuration ItemReader to read data from (A) and ItemWriter to write data to (B). 
(not just data copy. may be exist ItemProcessor)

How can I use transactionManager seperatly?

Is there Another way to configuration access multiple datasource in single Job?

Help me plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading can be done from a different datasource without problems because reading is unrelated respect to where SB metadata are saved.
Extracted from `JdbcCustomItemReader` javadoc:

> By default the cursor will be opened using a separate connection which
>   means that it will not participate in any transactions created as part
>   of the step processing.